# pass a collection of values to action, dynamically created textboxes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

I create textboxes dynamically with jquery. What i wonder how can i send those values into my action now with my viewmodel, kinda like this but instead of the httpPostedFileBase i want pass the values of the textboxes, I did name them like name="dTextboxes". Thanks for help im kinda stuck on this

```
public ActionResult Index(NewsViewModel viewModel, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this

```
public ActionResult Create(WorkViewModel viewModel, IEnumerable<string> dTextboxes)
```

and my dynamically textboxes looks like this

```
<input type="text" name="dTextboxes" />
<input type="text" name="dTextboxes" />
<input type="text" name="dTextboxes" />
```

and of cause in the action i do a foreach and check if string is not null after that do what i want with the string value of the textbox.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `IEnumerable<bool> dTextboxes` as action argument.

```
public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<bool> dTextboxes)
```

assuming that in your form you have:

```
<input name="dTextboxes[0]" type="checkbox" value="true" />
<input name="dTextboxes[0]" type="hidden" value="false" />

<input name="dTextboxes[1]" type="checkbox" value="true" />
<input name="dTextboxes[1]" type="hidden" value="false" />

<input name="dTextboxes[2]" type="checkbox" value="true" />
<input name="dTextboxes[2]" type="hidden" value="false" />

...
```

Comment: Is there any benefits of doing like this? my solution looks a lot cleaner though

Comment: @Dejan.S, both solution are possible. It's just that when dealing with checkboxes it seems more natural to me to work with boolean values (checked/unchecked) rather than strings.

Comment: oh yea i noticed that right now that you had checkboxes, im sorry. I had textboxes in my scenario that i needed. thanks for reply Darin

Comment: Dejan.S, I didn't read your question carefully. I thought that you wanted checkboxes instead of textboxes :-) With textboxes obviously your solution is the only correct one :-) I don't know why I was dreaming about checkboxes. Sorry for this confusion.